# Osmdroid CacheManager does not download tiles (0 named folders)

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm using osmdroid 5.1 and BonusPack 5.7 's CacheManager in order to cache the tiles of the currently displayed area. The problem is the download finished in a second and all I get is a bunch of 0 named folders for each specific zoom, which contains a 0.png.tile file .

Why can't I get the correct files?

Comment: Apparently .getBoundingBox() returns always the same value, which is obviously wrong. How to get the right coordinates ?

Comment: Are you calling .getBoundingBox() in onCreate? You can't. You have to wait for at least one map redraw to get a valid bounding box.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked :)